# Remote debugging - forward https?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging

Is it possible to forward locally-server site (but served with https) via remote debugging somehow?
[image]
My site is served via https because it uses some also https-based API. But it seems like there is no option now to forward it straightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work. If you forward port `1234` to `localhost:8080`, then you should be able to access `https://localhost:1234` on your device.

There's no spot to specify a protocol because it's a straight port forward.